# Sitecore add new Version for large number of items

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have a very large number of items that have versions on only 'en' language. 
I have to create 'de' versions for all these items. (switching the language to 'de' in content editor and clicking 'add new version' and thats all, nothing to translate). The items are children of a common parent and it applies to all the children of that parent root item.

what would be the most practical way to do this task?

**There is a challenge in this issue. I have access to only sitecore content editor with admin user. I cant program a script and run it on the system.**

Answer (score 1):

You would do something like this:

```
var master = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");

// Get the root folder of the items you want to create versions for.
var root = master.GetItem("path_or_GUID_to_root_item");

// Switch to the language you want to create versions for.
using (new LanguageSwitcher("de"))
{
    // Loop through all descendants.
    foreach (Item descendant root.Axes.GetDescendants())
    {
        // Create new version using the current context language.
        var version = descendant.Versions.AddVersion();

        // Lines below are optional if you want to add field values to the version.
        version.Editing.BeginEdit();
        version.Fields["field_name_or_GUID"] = "value";
        version.Editing.EndEdit();
    }
}
```

Bare in mind that `Axes.GetDescendants()` is not very performance-friendly if you have many items.
So if you're serious about it, use the ContentSearch API to retrieve the items.
But at least you get the idea on how to add a new version for a specific language.

Comment: The problem is, I dont have access to the web server. So I cant deploy anything. Thats why, I would like to research the options only available in sitecore content editor

Answer (score 1):

There is a module called `ItemVersioner` in the [Sitecore Marketplace](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_Item_Versioner.aspx). WIth this module you can create item versions of all available languages with one click. This has two drawbacks:

- You have to click on every item and click another time to add the versions. If your tasks is a one time task, it's maybe a solution anyway.
- It creates versions for all languages configured under `/sitecore/system/Languages`. If you have other versions than "en" and "de", you may have to delete them temporary if you don't want to create these versions too.

If this is not a solution, I think you must create some custom code. I think the code from [Ruud van Falier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21613236/2074649) is ok to start from. You need to create this code on your local machine and if this works for you, you can create a Sitecore package with this code (have a look on the [SDN here](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/65/package_designer_admin_guide-a4.pdf) for informations about how to create a package). You can then install this package on your system and start the code (you may also create a new ribbon which executes the code to create versions, check [this thread](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Forum/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=1252) for a starting point).

Comment: The ItemVersioner would have been cool if multiple language versions were to be created, but it  does not help me in this case. Manually clicking every item and clicking 'add new version' is also the same effort. The idea with ribbon sounds good to me. I will have a look at that, thanx

Answer (score 1):

If you really have no content to translate and you only want to display the en version of an item for de when it does not exist then you should consider using the [Language Fallback Module](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Language_Fallback.aspx), this is exactly what the module is designed to do.

If later you need to add de versions of items then you can do that on a case by case basis as the content gets added.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below URL to solve it -

http://www.cognifide.com/blogs/sitecore/quickly-create-new-language-versions-on-your-sitecore-cms/

http://blog.boro2g.co.uk/create-a-version-of-an-item-in-all-languages-in-the-sitecore-client/